# How can I strip '00:00:00' from a column in a table?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I recently migrated our application from MySQL to SQLite but since the migration I noticed something strange when storing time stamps.

Time stamps added when we were using MySQL look like `2015-01-01 00:00:00` but time stamps added now that we're using SQLite look like `2015-01-01`.

I do not need the `00:00:00` so it's not a problem, but how can I strip this from all existing rows from when we were using MySQL?

At the moment our column looks like:

```
user_EntryDate
--------------
2015-01-01 00:00:00
2015-01-02 00:00:00
2015-01-03 00:00:00
<switched to SQLite>
2015-01-04
2015-01-05
2015-01-06
```

Comment: what query have you tried?

Comment: What data type is that column in MySQL? (Additionally: SQLite does not have a data types for timestamp or date. Whatever you store in there is "plain text")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a database, you don't strip part of a value. Instead, you update the value you don't want to a value you do want.

This will update every row.

```
update your_table_name
set user_EntryDate = date(user_EntryDate);
```

You *could* use a WHERE clause to limit the update to only those rows that have time data. It might not be faster; it can't use an index.

```
update your_table_name
set user_EntryDate = date(user_EntryDate)
where user_EntryDate like '%00:00:00';
```